# increase score by mouse over event javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function createFlake(){
    var el= document.createElement('i');
    el.classList.add("fab");
    el.classList.add("fa-bitcoin")
    el.classList.add("fa-7x")
    el.style.left=Math.random()* window.innerWidth+'px';
    el.style.animationDuration= Math.random()*3+ 3 +'s';
    el.style.opacity=Math.random();

    let score=5;
    el.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{
        score=score+1;
        console.log(score)
        el.classList.add('fa-bitcoin-hover');
        var s=document.getElementById('scor');
        s.innerText="Score: "+score;

    })


    document.body.appendChild(el)

}
```

with above code, I am creating icons thats falling from top to bottom, and as I do that, every time that I mouse over the icon I want it to increase the score. everything works fine except i keep getting a same score or score+1. cant increase the score.

Comment: move `let score` outside the function unless you need each flake to have its own score

Comment: Also I suggest you clone a flake instead of creating a new one from scratch

Comment: It is not clear what you attempt to do. I have given two scenarios, 1 updates the score once for every mouseover. One updates the total of the scores where each mousover starts at 5 and counts for each coin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of taking a variable score, You can add score as property of the element. Simply `el.score`, see the code below:

```
el.score = 5;
el.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> {
    el.score++;
    console.log(el.score);
    el.classList.add('fa-bitcoin-hover');
    let s = document.getElementById('score');
    s.innerText = "Score:  " + el.score;
});
```

Comment: Why would this change anything? According to me that is what is happening already: The score is the value of whatever the current element has accumulated.

Comment: @mplungjan if there were multiple falkes, then score of one was copied to other. he needed to have individual score per flake. Just do a try of this in your example.

Comment: He already has individual scores. There is however only ONE scor element to show it with

Comment: @mplungjan that is difference in our understanding, he has ONE element to show score, and on mouse over of any icon, he just displays score of that particular icon. 
In your updated answer what you have in tooltips is the actual result he want in that ONE display-element.

Answer (score 1):

Move `let score` outside the function unless you need each flake to have its own score

```js
let score = 5;
const s = document.getElementById('scor');

function createFlake() {
  var el = document.createElement('i');
  el.classList.add("fab");
  el.classList.add("fa-bitcoin")
  el.classList.add("fa-7x")
  el.style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + 'px';
  el.style.animationDuration = Math.random() * 3 + 3 + 's';
  el.style.opacity = (Math.random()+0.009).toFixed(2); // or you get invisible flakes
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    score++
    el.classList.add('fa-bitcoin-hover');
    s.innerText = "Score: " + score;
  })
  document.body.appendChild(el)

}
createFlake()
createFlake()
createFlake()
createFlake()
```

```css
.fa-bitcoin-hover { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" />
<span id="scor">Score: 5</span>
<hr/>
```

If you get points each time you hit a flake, even when hitting the same flake more than once, you need something like this:

```js
const s = document.getElementById('scor');

const showScore = () => {
  let total = 0;
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".fab")].forEach(el => total += +el.title)
  s.innerHTML = total;
}
function createFlake() {
  var el = document.createElement('i');
  el.classList.add("fab");
  el.classList.add("fa-bitcoin")
  el.classList.add("fa-7x")
  el.style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + 'px';
  el.style.animationDuration = Math.random() * 3 + 3 + 's';
  el.style.opacity = (Math.random()+0.009).toFixed(2); // or you get invisible flakes
  let score = 5;
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    score++
    el.classList.add('fa-bitcoin-hover');
    el.title = score;
    showScore();
  })
  document.body.appendChild(el)

}
createFlake()
createFlake()
createFlake()
createFlake()
```

```css
.fa-bitcoin-hover { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" />
<div>Score: <span id="scor">5</span>
<hr/>
```